# Will the stored procedure be written to the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty new to SQL and I want to make sure I am not changing or editing anything on sql01 database.  I am allowed to read this database but not make any changes or edit anything.

The second database called called app02 is created and owned by me.  So I can do whatever with it.

Both databases are on different servers.

I am doing a query to see which FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME are listed in both databases.  When I run the below, I will be connected to my database app02 in SQL Server.  I am having to run a stored procedure to connect to the database not owned by me:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='sql01'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'sql01', 'false', NULL, 'username', 'password's
```

Will this save to or edit anything on the sql01 database?
Here is my complete query:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='sql01'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'sql01', 'false', NULL, 'username', 'password'

SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, STATUS, CLASS
  FROM sql01.database1.dbo.MyTable1 T1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
                FROM app02.database2.dbo.MyTable2 T2
                WHERE T1.FIRSTNAME = T2.FIRSTNAME
                AND T1.LASTNAME = T2.LASTNAME)
```

Comment: Whether it updates anything, will depend on what the stored procedure does. If the stored procedure just simply makes a connection, then you are good to go.  Your query specifically is only doing a  READ operation so nothing will be changed.

Comment: On top of Josh' comment, if the database is setup correctly to give you read-only access, then there should be nothing to worry about. If you attempt anything that may write something to the database, you will get a permission error and nothing will be written.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform **SELECT** Operation over any table then only you are viewing the Data from the table.When You use commands such as update ,delete then only the data structure will be modified.You can just use select statements and it will not change the database in the any sense.

Hope that this will help.